# A series of tm_map functions inside a function failing to work (R)

Tags: r, function, tm, corpus

I'm trying to avoid having to do a series of tm_map transformations by copypasting by hand, so I created an umbrella function to call on all of them at once, like so:

```
corpsify = function(x){
  x = tm_map(x, tolower)
  x = tm_map(x, removePunctuation)
  x = tm_map(x, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))
  x = tm_map(x, stripWhitespace)
  x = tm_map(x, stemDocument)
}
```

however, this is failing to work as intended. Reproducible example:

```
samplewords = c("and", "the", "lmao", "polite", "you", "youre", "yogurt")
corpus_sample = Corpus(VectorSource(samplewords))
corpsify(corpus_sample)
frequencies_sample = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_sample)
freq_sample = colSums(as.matrix(frequencies_sample))
freq_sample #this is to show that the corpus still contains all the words,
 # despite the function ostensibly removing stopwords and stemming words,
 # resulting in
> freq_sample
   and    the   lmao polite    you  youre yogurt 
     1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

however, when called individually like so

```
corpus_sample2 = Corpus(VectorSource(samplewords))
corpus_sample2 = tm_map(corpus_sample2, tolower)
corpus_sample2 = tm_map(corpus_sample2, removePunctuation)
corpus_sample2 = tm_map(corpus_sample2, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))
corpus_sample2 = tm_map(corpus_sample2, stripWhitespace)
corpus_sample2 = tm_map(corpus_sample2, stemDocument)
frequencies_sample2 = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_sample2)
freq_sample2 = colSums(as.matrix(frequencies_sample2))
freq_sample2
```

the end result is

```
> freq_sample2
  lmao  polit   your yogurt 
     1      1      1      1
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Is tm_map for some reason not a function I should use within a function?

Comment: You are assuming that `corpsify` modifies the original variable you pass into it. But R uses pass by value. You need `corpus_sample = corpsify(corpus_sample)`; and you should probably do `return(x)` for clarity at the end of the `corpsify` function.

Comment: Oh jeez, I have managed to use other similar functions completely correctly in this very same project but somehow missed that entirely. Thank you, that was a total brainfart that had me looking for a complex problem when I was just using a tool wrong. :E